# Number of app limit on Appstore?

Tags: app-store, google-play, appstore-approval, mac-app-store

Does anybody know if there is a limit on the number of apps I can upload/publish under my developer account? Couldn't find any reference to this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 4):

You can publish as many apps as you can get approved by Apple.  See [Apple's App approval guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/).  Submitting too many similar apps may be grounds for rejections, or even removal from the Developer program (section 2.20).  But there seem to exist developers with 100's of apps approved and in the iOS App store.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish **as many apps as you want** since you have your Developer License.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/